# Is Python uuid.uuid4 strong enough for password reset links?

Tags: python, security, cryptography, uuid

This is the code I use to generate a password reset link for my app:

```
def create_unique_code():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())
```

Is that strong enough? I use a one or two day expiry time.

Comment: That's totally fine, uuid4 is cryptosafe on cPython at least. A nice way to avoid storing those unique codes in the database is to to encode the user_id in the code itself. A nice example is how Django has implemented it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signing/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a UUID4 is fully random and long enough to rule out brute forcing or lucky guesses. So as long as whatever RNG `uuid.uuid4()` provides sufficiently good randomness you should be fine.

However, consider using e.g. a cryptographically signed token (the `itsdangerous` lib can take care of it) - not only can you specify an expiry time right when generating it, you also won't necessarily have to store anything about the token on your server.

Comment: maybe also worth mentioning the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module new in python3.6.

Answer (score 31):

In CPython, yes. In other Python implementations, probably, but you might want to double-check that a cryptographically strong source of randomness is used to generate the UUID.

---

There are two factors you might care about when judging whether some way of generating secure random tokens - such as UUIDs - is "strong enough":

1. Are there enough possible values for it not to be brute-forced?
2. Is the source of randomness used [cryptographically secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39186/what-does-it-mean-for-a-random-number-generator-to-be-cryptographically-secure)?

Since [there are 2<sup>122</sup> version 4 UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) (that's a little over 5 trillion trillion trillion), the answer to point 1 is definitely "yes", in this case. The space of all possible UUIDs ain't going to be brute forceable any time soon.

Point 2 is not currently answered by the [official Python docs on `uuid.uuid4()`](https://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4), which make no mention of security or whether the randomness source used is strong. Indeed, the entire documentation of `uuid4()` is just:

> Generate a random UUID.

which clearly provides no security guarantees.

Nor is it addressed by the [UUID specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), which does not mandate a cryptographically strong source of randomness be used in UUID generation and indeed explicitly contemplates the possibility of a *"predictable random number source"* being used to generate UUIDs in the **Security Considerations** section.

However, we can look at the implementation at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/uuid.py:

```
def uuid4():
    """Generate a random UUID."""
    return UUID(bytes=os.urandom(16), version=4)
```

Since this uses `os.urandom` as its randomness source, it's secure. See the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom which note that `os.urandom` returns:

> a string of *size* random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

Comment: bit of a side note, but does that mean that os.urandom can block? AFAIK anything that guarantees suitability for cryptographic purposes has the possibility of blocking at some point

Comment: @Cruncher, check the link for urandom in the answer, it appears that it can block.

Comment: Check the linux manpage: `man urandom`: "When a Linux system starts up without much operator interaction, the entropy pool may be in a fairly predictable state. This reduces the actual amount of noise in the entropy pool below the estimate."
As the manpage suggests, you need some gymnastics before using `/dev/urandom` for it to be considered cryptographically secure.

Comment: @MasoodKhaari Sure, but Python's `os.urandom` function *does* those gymnastics - see the linked docs.

Comment: @MarkAmery That's true from python 3.6 onward: 
"Changed in version 3.6.0: On Linux, `getrandom()` is now used in blocking mode to increase the security", i.e., python doesn't fall back on reading `/dev/urandom`.